# Django dropdown dependency on admin

Tags: django, admin, dropdown

i am only using the admin-interface of django , and i have a problem that , when someone select for exemple " country " i want to show on the second select the "city's " of that country.I have already done , my json file on my view and i want to get my json file and show it in javascript, and i dont know how to do it.

**MY APLICATION:**

```html
myproject/
     |-- myproject
     |-- daa/
         |-- avarias/
            |-- models.py
     |-- mapeamento/
          |-- models.py
          |-- views.py
     |-- static/
          |-- daa/
            |-- avarias/
              |-- admin/
                |-- js/
                  |-- example.js     
     |-- templates/
          |-- admin/
              |-- daa/
                  |-- change_form.html
```

**MY URLS**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls, name ='home'),
    path('rua/list/', get_ruas, name='get_ruas'),

]
```

**MY MODELS:**

```html
#Mapeamento Model

  class Freguesia(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField("Freguesia ID", primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField("Freguesia",max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):

        return  self.nome

  class Rua(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField("Rua id", primary_key=True)
    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nome = models.CharField("Rua",max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):

        return  self.nome
```

```html
#daa/avarias Model
    from mapeamento.models import freguesia
    from mapeamento.models import rua

class Avaria(models.Model):
    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Freguesia")
    rua = models.ForeignKey(Rua, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Rua")

    def __str__(self,):

        return str(self.id)
```

**MY MAPEAMENTO.VIEW**

```html
import json

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import Freguesia, Rua

def get_ruas(request): 
    freguesia_id = request.GET.get('freguesia_id')
    freguesia = get_object_or_404(Freguesia, pk=freguesia_id)
    res = Rua.objects.filter(freguesia=freguesia).order_by('nome').values('id', 'nome')
    result = {
        'ruas': list(Rua.objects.filter(freguesia=freguesia).order_by('nome').values('id', 'nome'))
    }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

**MY CHANGE_FORM.HTML**

```html
   {% extends "admin/change_form.html" %} 

   {% block extrahead %}
   {{ block.super }} 
    <script 
    # DO SOMETHING
   </script>
   {% endblock %}
```

So right now i dont know what to do , when i go to my browser and put **rua/list/?freguesia_id=10001** it is working , but now i want to show that values on my select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using django autocomplete light. Here are the [docs](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#using-autocompletes-in-the-admin).

This will give you the functionality to display options in the child filter based on the selection in parent filter with the help of its `forward` paramater.

Create a form class with city and country fields and then forward the field to city filter as:

```
class YourFormClass(forms.ModelForm):
    country = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all(), 
                                 widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='your_country_auto_url'),
                                 )
    city = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all(),
                                    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='your_city_auto_url',
                                                                     forward=['country']))

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Department View:

```
class YourViewAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            return City.objects.none()

        qs = City.objects.all()

        country = self.forwarded.get('country', None)

        if country:
            qs = qs.filter(country=country)

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

This will forward the selected `country` id and it can then be used in the autocomplete view to filter the city queryset. Please refer to the documentation to create autocomplete views to be used for the fields in the form.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, but is not that i am loocking for, i need the dropdown show the value's and i need to  select one.

Comment: i am trying to do that ,  but my form create a duplicate field like this https://prnt.sc/mmlpfy